# Rewriting a match in Coq

Tags: coq

In Coq, suppose I have a fixpoint function `f` whose matching definition on (`g x`), and I want to use a hypothesis in the form (`g x = ...`) in a proof. The following is a minimal working example (in reality `f`, `g` would be more complicated):

```coq
Definition g (x:nat) := x.

Fixpoint f (x:nat) := 
  match g x with
    | O => O
    | S y => match x with 
      | O => S O
      | S z => f z
      end 
  end.

Lemma test : forall (x : nat), g x = O -> f x = O.
Proof.
  intros.
  unfold f.
  rewrite H. (*fails*)
```

The message shows where Coq gets stuck:

```coq
(fix f (x0 : nat) : nat :=
   match g x0 with
   | 0 => 0
   | S _ => match x0 with
            | 0 => 1
            | S z0 => f z0
            end
   end) x = 0

Error: Found no subterm matching "g x" in the current goal.
```

But, the commands `unfold f. rewrite H.` does not work.

How do I get Coq to `unfold f` and then use `H` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```coq
Parameter g: nat -> nat.

(* You could restructure f in one of two ways: *)

(* 1. Use a helper then prove an unrolling lemma: *)

Definition fhelp fhat (x:nat) := 
  match g x with
    | O => O
    | S y => match x with 
      | O => S O
      | S z => fhat z
      end 
  end.

Fixpoint f (x:nat) := fhelp f x.

Lemma funroll : forall x, f x = fhelp f x.
destruct x; simpl; reflexivity.
Qed.

Lemma test : forall (x : nat), g x = O -> f x = O.
Proof.
  intros.
  rewrite funroll.
  unfold fhelp.
  rewrite H.
  reflexivity.
Qed.

(* 2. Use Coq's "Function": *)

Function f2 (x:nat) := 
  match g x with
    | O => O
    | S y => match x with 
      | O => S O
      | S z => f2 z
      end 
  end.

Check f2_equation.

Lemma test2 : forall (x : nat), g x = O -> f2 x = O.
Proof.
  intros.
  rewrite f2_equation.
  rewrite H.
  reflexivity.
Qed.
```

Comment: The issue is that Coq's ``simpl`` (and such like ``unfold, cbv, ...``) usually are too eager to simplify and unfold too much. Stating the rewriting lemma exactly as you need (``funroll`` here) with a really trivial proof, and using this lemma is a bit more complex, but yields better results in general.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this would solve the general problem, but in your particular case (since `g` is so simple), this works:

```
Lemma test : forall (x : nat), g x = O -> f x = O.
Proof.
  unfold g.
  intros ? H. rewrite H. reflexivity.
Qed.
```

Comment: From the question: "(in reality f, g would be more complicated)"

Comment: Yes, I saw that now. But  in all honesty, did the OP really submit a minimal working example? :-)

Answer (score 0):

Here is another solution, but of course for this trivial example. Perhaps will give you some idea. 
Lemma test2 : forall (x : nat), g x = O -> f x = O.
Proof.
=>intros;
  pattern x;
  unfold g in H;
  rewrite H;
  trivial.
Qed.